Find some basis of the subspace $U = \{ p \in \mathbb{R}_n[x] \;|\; p(1) = p(-1), \; p''(0) = 2p(1) \}$ where $n>3$
All I did so far is examine the first condition $p(1)=p(-1)$ and got $$a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}+\dots+a_1=0$$ if n is even, and $$a_{n}+a_{n-2}+\dots+a_0=0$$ if n is odd, where $a_n$ are the coefficients of some polynomial in U. For the second condition $p''(0) = 2p(1)$ I got $$a_n+a_{n-1}+\dots+a_3+a_1+a_0=0$$
I'm not sure what i can do with this information. How do I use it to find the basis?

Let $a_0,\cdots,a_{n-2}$ be "free". This then determines $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$. To write out explicit basis elements, you can set $a_i=1$, $a_0=\cdots=a_{i-1}=a_{i+1}=\cdots=a_{n-2}=0$, and then determine $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$ for different $i$.

We have $$U\cap {\rm span}\,\{1,x\}=\{0\}$$ Therefore $\dim U\le n-1.$ Let
$$V= \{p\in U\,:\, p(1)=0\}\subset U$$ Observe that  $x^4$ and  $x^{k}(x^2-1),$ $1\le k\le n-2,$ $k\neq
 2,$ belong to $V.$  These $n-2$ polynomials are linearly independent due to the fact that they have different degrees. Hence $\dim V\ge n-2.$ As $x^2\in U$ we obtain
$$W:={\rm span}\,\{x^2,V\}\subseteq U$$
Since $$\dim W=\dim V+1\ge n-1,\ \dim U\le n-1$$ we get $W=U.$
Thus the  polynomials $$x^2,\ x(x^2-1),\ \ x^4,\ x^{k}(x^2-1),\ 2<k\le n-2 $$ form a basis of $U.$ This basis has additional advantage that every element has different degree. For $k$ even we can replace $x^k(x^2-1)$ by $x^{k+2}.$
Remark We can slightly generalize the problem by requiring $p''(0)=ap(1)$ for $a\neq 0.$ The only modifiction would be $x^2+2a^{-1}-1$ in place of $x^2.$
